# Debugging app launched by push notification in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Similar to this question: [how to debug app when launch by push notification in xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672341/how-to-debug-app-when-launch-by-push-notification-in-xcode-5)

But for Xamarin Studio, does anyone know how to do it?

I would like the debugger to wait for the app to be launched manually by the user. Is it possible in Xamarin Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is currently not possible in Xamarin Studio.

If you file an enhancement request at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com you'll be notified if/when it's implemented.

Comment: Is it still the case?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to do that with Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio for Mac.

When debugging on an iOS device, if you use distribution profile, XS/VS4Mac will ask you to launch app manually (since distribution profile does not allow launching applications programmatically).

[image: launch app manually when debugging with distribution profile]

When VS4Mac will prompt you to start app manually, do not do that and also do not close that dialog.

Instead, send a push notification and then start application by tapping this notification.