# .navigationDestination race condition when app launches from user tapping notification in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a SwiftUI app that receives notifications. When a user taps on the notification from outside the app, the `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, did receive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}` method is called, and I use what I called NotificationParser to find the correct location in the app to navigate to, it gets the necessary information from the UNNotificationResponse.

I have an @Published Boolean property on my appDelegate that indicates whether the app should navigate to a different page.

On the Home Screen of my app, I have the appDelegate in an environment variable and a .navigationDestination like this

```
.navigationDestination(isPresented: $appDelegate.openedFromNotification, destination: {
                
                NotificationDestination()
                    
             //  Text("Testing if this gets opened at all")
                        
                        
                
            })
```

The problem that I am having is that when the app is closed (not running in the background) when a user taps on the notification, it opens the app and then navigates to a blank screen.

However, when the app is in the background, the app opens and navigates as expected to the correct page.

I assume that there is some sort of race condition with the app not having time to render the view properly before the NavigationStack pushes on a new view or something like that. I have tried making very simple views to be pushed on that wouldn't have to wait to load data from my server, but those also did not work. (When I comment out the NotificationDestination() and uncomment the Text in the above block, I still do not see anything when the view is pushed onto the stack.

I was able to get it to load correctly when I put a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) { }` around my updating the appDelegate.openedFromNotification property, but for obvious reasons, that produces a terrible experience when the app hangs for 5 seconds before navigating. (Smaller increments of time also worked inconsistently, but 5 seconds did it correctly every time). This fix seems really hacky to me, and I am sure there is a better way to do this, though I am not sure what that might be.

How can I get around this race condition?

Is there a better way to handle opening specific screens from push notifications?

I would appreciate any pointers that the community could provide.

P.S. Part of my problem is that because the bug only shows up when the app is closed, I do not know how to debug the app when it opens from a notification like that. [How to debug app when launch by push notification in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24672341/how-to-debug-app-when-launch-by-push-notification-in-xcode) shows how to run the app with an edited scheme that allows for the app not to launch immediately, but debugger output still does not show for me when I do this.

I have tried using different types of NavigationLinks and putting the .navigationDestination modifier at a few nearby levels of the view hierarchy.
I have also tried using simpler views as the destination that doesn't require any external data.

Here is a minimum reproducible set of code. I did ten tries with this demo opening the app from the notification when it was closed and when it was in the background. I got to the correct screen 10/10 times when the app was in the background and 2/10 times when the app was closed. The app either did not navigate anywhere, or navigated to a blank screen.

After turning on Push Notifications in a new project, this code should recreate the problem.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct navigationDestinationApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(appDelegate)
        }
    }
}

class NotificationParser {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func getNotificationDestination(response: UNNotificationResponse?) -> some View {
        if response == nil { Text("Response is nil and not updated.") }
        else {
            
            if Bool.random() {
                Text("View option 1")
            } else {
                Text("View option 2")
            }
            
        }//: else not nil
    }//: getNotificationDestination
    
}//: NotificationParser




class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var openedFromNotification: Bool = false
    @ViewBuilder
    func notificationDestination() -> some View {
        NotificationParser().getNotificationDestination(response: self.notificationResponse)
    }
    @Published var notificationResponse: UNNotificationResponse? = nil
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
                     [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        //TODO: I should move this somewhere else where it does not spam the user immediately after they download the app.
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { granted, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error in requesting notification authorization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            if granted {
                // Register after we get the permissions.
                UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
            }
        }
        
        
        
        return true
    }
    
    
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void
    ) {
        //MARK: This happens when the app is in the background and a silent notification is received.
        print("application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult)")
        
    
        
    }
    
    
    
    //Tapped on a notification from outside the app.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        
        
        
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.notificationResponse = response
                self.openedFromNotification = true
            }
            completionHandler()
            
        
        
    }
    
    // App in foreground
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        
        print("Received notification while in foreground.")
    }
    
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appDelegate: AppDelegate
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                
                Button("Schedule new notification") {
                    NotificationService().scheduleTimerNotification(title: "You asked for this!", subtitle: "Your app is ready to view", numSeconds: 5)
                    
                }//: Button
            }//: VStack
            .navigationDestination(isPresented: $appDelegate.openedFromNotification, destination: {
                appDelegate.notificationDestination()
            })
            .padding()
        }//: NavigationStack
    }//: body
}

import Foundation
import UserNotifications


class NotificationService {
    
    //Schedule notification for 10 seconds from now to give time to close the app.
    func scheduleTimerNotification(title: String, subtitle: String, numSeconds: Double = 10, sound: UNNotificationSound = .default, identifier: String = "NotificationTest") {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent ( )
        content.title = title
        content.subtitle = subtitle
        content.sound = sound
        
        if numSeconds <= 0 { return }
        //Set the notification to repeat every 10 seconds
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger (timeInterval: numSeconds, repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest (identifier: identifier, content: content,
        trigger: trigger)
        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after many hours of digging through logs and such. The problem was that the

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

was inside the completion handler of

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge])
```

That meant that the app delegate was not actually the delegate of the UNNotificationCenter when the notification was processed. Moving that line outside of the completion handler works like a charm.